# Limits of phpOCR

Tags: php, ocr

I downloaded phpOCR, and found that it can be use full if the image file you have has one word, however it is not that useful if the image has two or more words and use different fonts.

I am wondering if anyone has ever used the PHP OCR and what they have found to be its limits.

Comment: Why not try Tesseract? It's easy to parse the output (it's plain text).

Comment: because I don't understand how to use that with PHP.

Comment: `tesseract image.tif` produces `image.txt`, which is filled with the OCR text. It is about as plain as it gets.

Comment: @Blender Yes I understand that but a PHP example would be great, and also the issue is that it needs to be able to run on a web-server (CentOS 5) and not windows XP

Comment: Tesseract should be available in your distro's package repositories. As for the example, Google **PHP run command**. You need to execute that above command and read that `txt` file. It's quite simple.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I used phpOCR some time. Is quite good but you need a minimum size of images to be effective (I don't remember but for example chars of 1 cm height). If you need it to parse captchas, forget it...

Comment: No I don't want to use it for that, I want to use it so that I can scan a bill, find words and get the things I need out of it

Comment: I'm sorry for such example :( I remember that finally used a linux OCR utility in some way to feed the php script. Allow best results. Good luck!

Comment: Would you remember which Linux OCR you used?

Comment: [ocrad](http://www.gnu.org/software/ocrad/) (the characters should be at least 20 pixels high) At that time I tried: `Now I'm trying to convert the gif image to a vector-based one, then enlarge it, then decrease edges (to separate letters) and then pass it trough a OCR program. All this should be run automatically on your server. Which should be at least a VPS.` That's an explanation for my client 2 years ago about a scraping job. Unfortunately I can add more due the source suddenly was converted to html being unnecessary make all these procedures. But as you see it is possible.